# Adding only sub-classes instances to my collection class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist, collections

I am writing a program with different classes and there there is a collection class which will store only the sub-classes of the superclass.
Okay, so i have an `Order` super class that stores quantity. The code snippet is like this:

```
abstract class Order { //superclass
 private int quantity; //instance variables

 public Items(int quantity) { //constructor
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }

 public int getQuantity() { // instance method
  return quantity;
 }

 public abstract double totalPrice();
```

Then i have sub-classes of the `order` class. The sub-classes are below.

```
class Coffee extends Order { //subclass 
 private String size; //instance variables

 public Coffee (int quantity, String size) { //constructor
  super(quantity);
  this.size = size;
 } //... some other methods
} // end of Coffee class

class Donuts extends Order { //sub-class
 private double price; //instance variables
 private String flavour;

 public Donuts(int quantity, double price, String flavour) { //constructor
  super(quantity);
  this.price = price;
  this.flavour = flavour;
 } //...some other methods
} //end of donut class

class Pop extends Order {
 private String size;
 private String brand;

 public Pop(int quantity, String size, String brand) {
  super(quantity);
  this.size = size;
  this.brand = brand;
 } //...again there are some other methods
} //end of pop sub-class
```

Now this is where i need help. I have written a collection class that contains `ArrayList<>`. The code snippet is this:

```
class OrderList {
 private ArrayList<Order> list;

 public OrderList() {
  list = new ArrayList<Order>();
}
```

**What i want to do in the collection class is to have instance methods that ensure that only sub-classes are only added to my collection class.***

What i have tried so far is this (which makes me a complete fool, i know that).

```
public void add(Coffee cof) {
 list.add(cof);
}
public void add(Donut don) { // i know we cant have methods with the same name
 list.add(don);
}

public void add(Sandwich sand) {
 list.add(sand);
}

public void add(Pop p) {
 list.add(p);
}
```

SO community can you please give me some hints on my problem.

Comment: I am ready to provide more details though.

Comment: Well, it will always be a sub-class, because you can't instantiate an abstract class

Comment: Do you want only specific subclasses to be added?

Comment: You _can_ have methods with the same name, it's the signature that matters.

Comment: is it possible to have methods with the same name? @Marvin

Comment: yea only those classes that extend my super-class @flakes

Comment: You just need one `add(Order order)` method.  Since Order is abstract, you can't create an 'Order' object directly; it can only be created through a sub-class.  (I assume @flakes means _can't_, not _can_.)

Comment: Did you actually try to compile anything? Those methods with the same name all have different signatures, so they're all valid.

Comment: @Saad: Read about method overloading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: @pathfinderelite you are correct in that assumption lol

Comment: @Saad But will it be ALL classes that extend your super class, or just some? Say you later have a `class NewThing extends Order` will `NewThing` need to go into that list too? If so then use the answer @pathfinderelite provided

Comment: yeah, All classes. I used pathfinderelite's method and it works, however Marvin said that i can use methods with the same name but it is giving me errors. @flakes

Comment: Maybe i am doing something wrong on how i am adding those objects. I am doing something like this in my main method, `object = new Coffee(quantity, size);` and `list.add(object); //store`  I am going through the link Marvin provided me. @flakes

Comment: Make sure `object` is casted as an `Order` and not as an `Object`

Comment: @Saad Marvin pointed out, that the methods signature matters. The signature is the method name and the types of the methods input parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting your abstractions **wrong**. A Product .. isn't an Order.

A Product is simply a Product. It has some "identity", and probably different "flavors". But when you think about it, initially, it is not an order. An order comes into existence when a customer selects various products, puts them into some shopping card ... and hits the "order" button.

Just think how things are "in the real" world. And that is what should guide the model that you build.

Meaning: your Products should not subclass Order. Instead, you could be doing something like:

```
public abstract class ShopItem {
  // that contains those things that all products in the shop have in common, like
  public abstract double getPrice();
```

...

and then all your Products extend that class. It might be even more useful to avoid inheritance here completely, and turn ShopItem into an **interface** (that would depend if you really find good reasons to use an abstract class; in order to define **common** behavior of ShopItems).

Next:

```
public class ProductOrder {
  private final ShopItem orderedItem ...
  private final int quantity ...
```

And to bring things together:

```
public final class Order {
  private final List<ProductOrder> allItemsOfAnOrder ...
```

Comment: Not sure where you are getting that last part from, since nothing like that was in the question and may be more than what he was gambling for. `List<Order>` is sufficient to add any object to it that extends `Order`. By making it `List<? extends Order>`, it just means that you could assign an actual `List` implementation to the variable that uses a generic that extends `Order`. But I'd question the usefulness of that for anything but collections that get passed in from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature will be:

```
public void add(Order order){
...
}
```

because an Order can hold reference to any of its subtypes.

Comment: Please don't just copy&paste comments. At least explain why it works.

Comment: Parent classes don't hold references to their subtypes

Comment: @Federico please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the need for your own `OrderList`. Since `Order` is an abstract class, you can only add instances of non-abstract child classes to any `List<Order>` that you declare.

Also, instead of

```
class OrderList {
    private ArrayList<Order> list;

    public OrderList() {
        list = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }
}
```

you can also use

```
class OrderList extends ArrayList<Order> {

    public OrderList() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and then simply use the `add(Order element)` that you inherited from your parent class.

But then again, it might be more convenient to just declare an `ArrayList<Order>` wherever you intended to use your `OrderList`, as long as you don't add any new methods (that are not given by a regular `List`) to justify having an extra class.